# conditional probability of an ace being drawn and then a king

Tags: probability

I am trying to study for my statistic exam and not sure how to solve this question. The question is :

what is the possibility of the following event: 
an ace is drawn first and a king is drawn second.

Here is what I have done but not sure if its right.

Using the conditional probability formula :
$$P(A|B) = P(A \cap B)/P(B).$$

so `A = ace is drawn ==> 4/52 ==> 1/13` and `B = king is drawn ==> 1/13`. 
so now I am not sure how to do $$P(B \cap A)$$
could someone direct me from this point on as to what I need to do to solve this?

Comment: Are you drawing with replacement or without replacement?

Comment: without replacement...

Comment: By the way, the title should not be "Conditional probability $\dots$." We are just finding the probability. I gave a solution that *used* conditional probabilities, but it was the probability that second is King *given* that first is Ace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability that the first card drawn is an Ace is $\frac{4}{52}$.  **Given** that an ace was drawn first, there are $51$ cards left, so the (conditional)  probability that a King is drawn next is $\frac{4}{51}$. Thus our required probability is 
$$\frac{4}{52}\cdot\frac{4}{51}.$$

We can use more machinery. Let $A$ be the event an Ace was drawn first, and let $B$ be the probability that a King is drawn second. We want $P(A\cap B)$.
By the usual formula
$$P(A\cap B)=P(B|A)P(A).$$
We have $P(A)=\frac{4}{52}$ and $P(B|A)=\frac{4}{51}$. Multiply.
Note that this is the same solution as the first one!

**Another way:** Record the result of the first two drawings as an ordered pair $(X,Y)$. For example, $X$ could be "Jack of $\spadesuit$," and $Y$ could be "$2$ of $\clubsuit$."

There are $(52)(51)$ such ordered pairs, all equally likely.

How many have the shape $(U,V)$ where $U$ is one of the $4$ Aces, and $V$ is one of the $4$ Kings? Clearly $(4)(4)$. So our probability is
$$\frac{(4)(4)}{(52)(51)}.$$

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, another quick question. I have read that you can not rewrite `(A and B)` as `P(A) * P(B)` unless they are independent events, and in my case, the cards are dependent events and I noticed that you use `P(A) * P(B)`. could you maybe explain this whole dependent and independent thing a bit more for me?

Comment: If you look at the answer again, you will see that I did not use $P(A)P(B)$.  I used $P(A)P(B|A)$.  The **unconditional** probability of $B$, called $P(B)$, is the probability that the second card is a King, given **no** information about the result of the first draw. It turns out that $P(B)=\frac{4}{52}$. This fact was not used in the calculation. Explaining the whole dependent/independent thing would take a long time. But one can say that $A$ and $B$ are independent if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. First card Ace, second card King are **not** independent.

Comment: again thanks alot for your time. that helped alot and cleared things up.

Comment: I posted another question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115176/a-probability-question-using-percentages   Would appreciate it if you could take a look.