# Probability of a pulling a card (king) followed by any other card(s) that are not kings

Tags: probability, card-games

Im trying to learn how to calculate the probability of events and Im unsure how to evaluate one of my practice questions.

"What is the probability of pulling a king out of a pack of 52 cards followed by 2 consecutive cards that are not kings"

My attempt:

$$\frac{4}{52}\cdot\frac{48}{51}\cdot\frac{47}{50}$$

Im unsure whether this is correct, as im presuming that once you pick the king you have to deduct the king from the pack, and since you are not looking for kings you remove all 4 from the options resulting in:

$$\frac{48}{51}$$

Im confused as whether this is the correct way to calculate the result and after looking at some online [tutorials on stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115151/conditional-probability-of-an-ace-being-drawn-and-then-a-king#_=_) I remain somewhat still uncertain, as im unsure whether I should subtract a card from the 48 as the first card picked is a king...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks correct to me, your logic seems fine.

Comment: great, thanks for  telling me :)